# How can I open a csv in excel and apply conditional formatting all in one step?

Tags: python, excel, csv

Just like the title suggests, I want to open csv data and apply conditional formatting to it in excel.  Ideally I want to do this through excel functionality, but I'm not opposed to scripting with a language (like say python, or c#, as I know they have excel api support).

In more detail; what I'm doing is data logging. I am reporting process data and I want to mark values as either green or red (pass / fail) for the operators when they open up the csv in excel.  These conditional formats are simply based off whether they are above or below a certain threshold/tolerance.

So I want this to be as simple as possible for the operator.  Ideally just run one script, or open up a spreadsheet that's already got the conditional rules written and just needs to be pointed to the correct csv source.. or something along those lines.

Is this possible?  I don't need you to actually write anything for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction in terms of how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Create a VBA sub, where you define variables as colors with respective codes. Utilize a select case and it should do the trick:

```
   Sub condFormat ()

    csvOpen

    Dim myVal As Double 
    Dim myCol As Long 

    myVal = Range("A1").Value 'example 'Determine which case it is
    Select Case myVal
     Case Is < 0 myCol = 14
     'Green 
    Case Is < 0.1 myCol = 6
     'Red Case Else myCol = 3 'Red 

    End Select 'Color

 Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = myCol

End Sub

Function csvOpen() 

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Desktop\myfile.csv" 

End function
```

Comment: You're describing how to conditionally format.. which is not what I'm having issues with. I'm wondering how I can open a csv and apply a pre written conditional format, or macro, or VBA sub, without retyping it every time. I want an operator to double click something, like the csv or another excel file or a script, that does all this.

Comment: My mistake, code is editet. I added function to open the csv file firstly, then apply formatting. You may need to alter the filename part and change to a variable if the file do not have the same name/location every time. Also, assign the sub condFormat to a button for your operator to click on, or simply add it into ThisWorkbook VBA and make it run when opening.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks bud.